# Is there a way to get the survey count totals using the SurveyMonkey API?

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I have been working with the SurveyMonkey API for a few days now.

My ultimate goal is to be able to gather the voting results for each question in a survey.

For example... if I have a 5 question survey and each question has 3 options/answers... I'd like to gather the results of each question/option.

From what I'm finding in the API documentation... this is not possible.

Can this really not be possible?

Is there a way to gather the results of each question/answer combo using the API?

I hope I'm simply overlooking something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to get this kind of information - you can get the metadata of the survey via the API and all response data. How you process and parse that is up to you.

The most common use case to get a list of survey results is done the following way:

- Get a list of respondent_ids via [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/methods/get_respondent_list/)
- Send these respondent_ids to [get_responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/methods/get_responses/) to get the raw response data
- Match up the ids from this data with the ids described in the survey's metadata, which you get from [get_survey_details](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/methods/get_survey_details/)